# Chat bubbles in bootstrap and flex?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I need code chat bubbles within bootstrap framework where I distinguish right and left bubbles with 2 class, e.g. `right` and `left`.

Each bubble should have max width, e.g. 70% but should be less if text isn't too large.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="justify-content-end">
    <p class="col-6 msg right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque neque est, viverra ac rhoncus et, cursus eu leo. Quisque in tristique libero, sed rhoncus neque. Ut at enim id ligula consequat tempus in nec magna. Donec vitae libero eget mi malesuada
      rutrum. Integer ornare ante at ligula venenatis, quis blandit urna euismod. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="justify-content-end">
    <p class="col-6 msg left">Integer ornare ante at ligula venenatis, quis blandit urna euismod.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="justify-content-start">
    <p class="col-6 msg right">Integer ornare ante at ligula venenatis, quis blandit urna euismod.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="justify-content-end">
    <p class="col-6 msg left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque neque est, viverra ac rhoncus et, cursus eu leo. Quisque in tristique libero, sed rhoncus neque. Ut at enim id ligula consequat tempus in nec magna. Donec vitae libero eget
      mi malesuada rutrum. Integer ornare ante at ligula venenatis, quis blandit urna euismod. ge</p>
  </div>
  <div class="justify-content-start">
    <p class="col-6 msg right">Integer ornare ante at ligula venenatis, quis blandit urna euismod.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.msg {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.msg.right {
  background-color:#CCC;
}

.msg.left {
  background-color:#555;
  color: white;
}
```

I also put code into jsfiddle. I tried use `justify-content-xxx` But it doesn't work as I expected. Can you tell me how to do that with much simpler way? Thanks in advice.

https://jsfiddle.net/3a9vhydk/4/

Comment: You probably shouldn't use Bootstrap for the chat bubbles, it's not really designed for it. Otherwise you could just float them to the right: `.right { float: right; }`

Comment: @DavidG but bootstrap has util classes for flex and for float as well. But I am new in html / css coding so I don't know how to combine it to required result.

Comment: Use Bootstrap right up to the point it starts getting in your way, then inside the div you want something special to happen, just use plain CSS.

Comment: @DavidG can you edit my example to show how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a float: right to the 'right' class and take out the justify-content bit on the containing divs.

I modified your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Mikkal24/0r5snvxu/

```
.msg.right {
  background-color:#CCC;
  float: right;
}
```

Updated Version : https://jsfiddle.net/Mikkal24/534kn62w/

**Note** no floats only flex

Comment: it doesn't work for short messages, check it please https://jsfiddle.net/0r5snvxu/1/ I need set max width as I wrote e.g. 70% but it could be less if message is shorter

Comment: Ah, well in that case flex is kind of the way to go. I re-factored your original code a bit and this is what I come up with. https://jsfiddle.net/Mikkal24/534kn62w/

The reason why your gray box was filling it's container is because you applied col-6 to it.